# JavaScript Form HTML

Tags: javascript

Evening,

I have to validate a HTML form by pushing it through a Javascript function to make sure no illegal characters are in it. How would I do it for Customer Number and separately for Password but in the same form as they both need to go through to login.jsp

```
<form onsubmit="return validateNum(this)" action="login.jsp" >          
        Customer Number: <input type="text" name="customerNumber"/><br/>
        Password: <input type="password" name="passphrase"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

I am aware that it is completely pointless doing it through Javascript as it can be disabled via the browser and a better way would be through the HTML form its self but that is the parameter that has been set.

I have

```
function validateNum(fld)
    {           
    var error = "";
    var illegalNum =  /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\"\[\]]/[a-z][A-Z];

    if (fld.value.length == 0) {
        fld.style.background = 'Yellow'; 
        error = "The required field has not been filled in.\n"
    } 
    else if (fld.value == "") {
    fld.style.background = 'Yellow'; 
    error = "You didn't enter a Customer Number.\n";
        }
    else {
    fld.style.background = 'White';
            }   
    }
```

It's half finished as I realized if I put illegal characters A-Z then the password wont work .

Comment: Have you tried googling 'javascript form validation'?

Comment: it should be validated on client side AND server side

Comment: @DA I have looked into it but I haven't found anything on two separate inputs in one form. The validation goes through to login.jsp to be checked against the database.

Comment: I don't know what to say, other than 'keep googling'. :) Validating forms with JS is nothing new and there are dozens and dozens of examples out there for you to look at. As it is, the question "how to validate a form with JS" just just too broad.